# Protected/runtime not valid error on Mac yii

Tags: php, macos, yii2, chmod

I am trying to setup my website configuration in my Mac OS but it keeps giving me an error like below

> /protected/runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.

I tried to give permission to that folder but it is still not working. Maybe I am giving permission incorrectly. How can I give permission to that folder through terminal?

I also tried giving permission to Apache user so that it works with all projects but it's not working. I tried doing the following:

```
chgrp apache /path/to/mydir
chmod g+w /path/to/mydir
```

It throws an error that there are not groups. I am using Xampp latest version for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below command:

```
chmod -fR 0777 path/to/yii/folder/protected/runtime
```

It will generate the log into runtime directory. So you must have to provide the 777 permission to his directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
chmod -R 755 path/to/yii/folder
```

Comment: @MikeRoss : May be path to the folder is Wrong. Please check